# How can i define routes for logged user?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I can save successfuly the data in the local storage and access to my array like this :

```
        var user = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['user'] || '{}');
        console.log(user);
```

user.loken contain my token, so if the user token exist and is in the local storage it means that the user is logged.

Now my question are :

If the user is logged, he don't need to have access to the login page. If the user is logged he has to be redirected to tab/.

i don't know how to make the condition, i have read that i have to make a factory and define a variable hcih say that if the token exist set the variable as true and then you can use that everywhere. Is it correct ?

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html',
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $stateChangeStart:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

 if (!window.localStorage['user'].token) {           
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go("login");
        return;
 }
}
```